# Can I make this a Monad

Tags: haskell, gadt

I've got a type `T` (which if you're interested, is a wrapper of static-pointers I've been exploring [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/static-closure)) where I can happily write the following operations for:

```
unpointT :: T a -> a
apT :: T (a -> b) -> T a -> T b
bindT :: T a -> (a -> T b) -> T b
```

The problem is, I don't have an unrestricted `pure` function. `pure` must be constrained by in my case, some constraint which says the type is serialisable, such as `Binary`.

```
pureT :: C a => a -> T a
```

Note that both `apT` and `bindT` are unrestricted.

This all looks fairly monad like, but with the only issue being the restricted pure. Is there anyway, perhaps with some `GADT` wrapping/unwrapping, that I can get this to work with the standard `Monad` hierarchy?

If not, is there an alternate hierarchy that exists, that restricts `pure` but keeps `<*>` and `>>=` unrestricted?

Note also that `T a` can still be valid for some `a` even though `pure (x :: a)` is not, for example by combining `T (b -> a)` and `T b` with `ap`.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a pointer to no location in your data type? I am asking this because the `unpointT` definition leads me to believe that cannot be the case. Thus, you might be able to derive a comonad instead, provided you can write a sound version of `extend`. Another idea would be to see if you can deal with the restriction using a technique such as outlined here http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/set-monad.html

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific about the definition of your `T` and `C` to get a definitive answer.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson C is usually something like Binary and T is https://hackage.haskell.org/package/static-closure-0.1.0.0/docs/Control-Static-Closure.html#t:Closure

Comment: Put the definitions in your question

Comment: do you think you could construct `T (a->b)` for your appT?

Comment: Other things that might have some relevance: (1) [The `Apply` and `Bind` classes from *semigroupoids*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids); (2) [Some form of constrained monads](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/constrained-categories/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: If you have `unpointT` then you have a sensible way of constructing `bindT`. But do you really have an unrestricted `apT`? It seems to be a `pureT` hidden there

Answer (score 0):

It won't work as it is as a monad as the right identity law is not satisfied.

`bindT m pureT` has type `C a => T a` while `m` has type `T a`. These two should always be equal but these are not even of the same type.

Comment: This is fundamentally right, but I feel it would be clearer to put it in a different way. On the one hand, it is perfectly possible for the right identity law to be satisfied as long as the type of `m` fits `C a => T a`; on the other hand, the law can't be applied if the type of `m` doesn't fit -- `\m -> bindT m pureT` has type `C a => T a -> T a`. (My point is that `T` may well be a monad, but it can't be a `Monad` because of the constraint.)